# I get an unbound variable error when I load this function from a file with mit-scheme

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

I'm learning scheme as part of a university course.

I tried saving this code to the file fact-iter-001.scm:

```
(def (fact n)
  (def (fact-iter result counter)
    (if (> counter n)
        result
        (fact-iter (* result counter) (+ counter 1))))
  (fact-iter 1 1))
```

When I try loading it into scheme, I gen an unbound variable error for fact-iter:

[image: unbound variable: fact-iter]

From my understanding of the code, "fact-iter" is defined locally inside the "fact" procedure, therefore it should be available when it is called just after being defined. Before writing this question, I also checked the book "Structure and interpretation of computer programs", where there is an almost identical example.

I'm assuming that either my understanding of the code is totally wrong, or I'm loading the file in the wrong way, but I can't understand which and why. Can anyone help?

Comment: Scheme uses `define`, not `def`.

Comment: Is there perhaps a definition for `def` given by your professor?

Comment: That's the beauty of having to study different lisp dialects at the same time. It's a very obvious error, still I would never have spotted it. Thank you for pointing it out.